# How to use conditional add_action for Wordpress

Tags: actions

I am having a small issue where i need to call `add_action` method which is conditional.
Basically here, first checking whether the plugin active or not by `admin_init` action. If true then i need another `add_action` call from that action.

Please find the scenario what i am looking for:

```
        function check_some_other_plugin() {
            if ( is_plugin_active('some-plugin.php') ) {
                    //if true then vc_before_init action will run
                    add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_master_home_slider' );
            }
        }
        add_action( 'admin_init', 'check_some_other_plugin' );

        function vc_master_home_slider() {
            //my stuff
        }
```

I will really appreciate if somebody answer me to find actual way to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

just check inside the action ^^

```
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_master_home_slider' );

function vc_master_home_slider(){
  if(is_plugin_active('some-plugin.php'){
    //Do stuff.
  }
}
```